# Fix activity leak when listener keeps implicit reference

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-leaks, listener

In the **MessageFeedActivity onCreate** method it load feeds by calling **getMessageTypes** method of **CTFeedAPI** class.

```
public class MessageFeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  //Setting the listener
  CTFeedAPI ctFeedAPI = new CTFeedAPI(new CTFeedAPI.CTFeedAPIListener() {
   @Override
   public void feedAPISuccessListener(Object object) {
    // Handle Success
   }

   @Override
   public void feedAPIErrorListener(int error) {
    // Handle Error
   }
  });

  ctFeedAPI.getMessageTypes();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
 }
}
```

and wait for **CTFeedAPIListener** response. And **CTFeedAPI** class make network request by calling **performRequest** method of **NetworkRequest** class as

```
public class CTFeedAPI implements NetworkListener {
 private CTFeedAPIListener apiListener;

 public CTFeedAPI(CTFeedAPIListener feedAPIListener) {
  apiListener = feedAPIListener;
 }

 public void getMessageTypes() {
  Map < String, String > params = new HashMap < > ();
  params.put("f", "GetMessageTypes");

  NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest(this);
  networkRequest.performRequest();
 }

 public interface CTFeedAPIListener {
  void feedAPISuccessListener(Object object);

  void feedAPIErrorListener(int error);
 }
}
```

and wait for **NetworkListener** response

```
public class NetworkRequest {
 private NetworkListener mListener;

 public interface NetworkListener {

  void networkReqSuccessListener(String cacheKey, String tag, String response);

  void networkReqErrorListener(String tag, int error);
 }
 public NetworkRequest(NetworkListener listener) {
  this.mListener = listener;
 }

 public void performRequest(
  // Perform Network Requests and respond as
  if (mListener != null) {
   if (success) {
    mListener.networkReqSuccessListener(getUrl(), getTag(), response);
   } else {
    mListener.networkReqErrorListener(getTag(), err_msg);
   }
  }
 }
```

When users press back key, before destroy the MessageFeedActivity, the system call 'onDestroy' method. And Unfortunately, because the background thread (performRequest method in NetworkRequest class) is still keep a reference to it, leak occurs.

So how to implement **CTFeedAPIListener** reference in MessageFeedActivity to remove leak.

Answer (score 2):

In this design not only you will leak memory but also your code would be highly coupled and very hard to test; prone to bugs that are hard to detect. I would suggest you implement MVP or similar architecture. Your activity should never know anything about your network layer. Add a presenter layer that is responsible to request something on behalf of your activity and use interface to update your activity. Your presenter should access a business entity that is mapped from the response of repository layer, that is responsible for network or Db access and return values to the client presenter. This way your presenter and business logic layers would be decoupled and easy to test independently. In the future if business requirements change, your changes don't affect other layers. Please see [this article for more information on the subject](https://medium.com/@pavan.careers5208/detailed-guide-on-android-clean-architecture-9eab262a9011).

Comment: Thanks to reply, actually CTFeedAPI class have methods related to Feeds calls with server and NetworkRequest have methods to call with Network library volley. That's why I had created two classes.

Comment: As you told **use interface to update your activity.* *, I think I have used **CTFeedAPIListener** to link with activity.

Answer (score 1):

> Weak reference objects, which do not prevent their referents from
>   being made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. Weak references
>   are most often used to implement canonicalizing mappings.
>
> Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in
>   time that an object is weakly reachable. At that time it will
>   atomically clear all weak references to that object and all weak
>   references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that
>   object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references. At
>   the same time it will declare all of the formerly weakly-reachable
>   objects to be finalizable. At the same time or at some later time it
>   will enqueue those newly-cleared weak references that are registered
>   with reference queues.

You can use Weak Reference:

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class NetworkRequest {
 public interface NetworkListener {
      void networkReqSuccessListener(String cacheKey, String tag, String response);
      void networkReqErrorListener(String tag, int error);
 }

 private WeakReference<NetworkListener> mListener;

 public NetworkRequest(NetworkListener listener) {
      this.mListener = new WeakReference<NetworkListener>(listener);
 }

 public void performRequest(){
  // Perform Network Requests and respond as
  NetworkListener listener = mListener.get();
  if (listener != null) {
     if (success) listener.networkReqSuccessListener(getUrl(), getTag(), response);
     else listener.networkReqErrorListener(getTag(), err_msg);
   }
  }
}
```

---

```
public class CTFeedAPI implements NetworkListener {
 private WeakReference<CTFeedAPIListener> apiListener;

 public CTFeedAPI(CTFeedAPIListener feedAPIListener) {
  apiListener = new WeakReference<>(feedAPIListener);
 }

 public void getMessageTypes() {
  Map < String, String > params = new HashMap < > ();
  params.put("f", "GetMessageTypes");

  NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest(this);
  networkRequest.performRequest();
 }

 public interface CTFeedAPIListener {
  void feedAPISuccessListener(Object object);

  void feedAPIErrorListener(int error);
 }
}
```

---

save `CTFeedAPI` and `CTFeedAPIListener` as instance variable of `MessageFeedActivity` to prevent `GC` collecting them when activity is presented:

```
public class MessageFeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CTFeedAPI ctFeedAPI = null;// keeping a reference to CTFeedAPI
private CTFeedAPIListener listener = null;// keeping a reference to listener
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  //Setting the listener
  listener = new CTFeedAPI.CTFeedAPIListener() {
   @Override
   public void feedAPISuccessListener(Object object) {
    // Handle Success
   }

   @Override
   public void feedAPIErrorListener(int error) {
    // Handle Error
   }
  });
  ctFeedAPI = new CTFeedAPI(listener);
  ctFeedAPI.getMessageTypes();
 }
```

Comment: As mentioned NetworkRequest class use to load network request in background thread and while performing request if I use WeakReference as you have suggested, NetworkListener getting null while network response, because CTFeedAPI class  remove ref of NetworkRequest class.

Comment: @GiruBhai save `CTFeedAPI` as instance variable of `MessageFeedActivity` to prevent `GC` collecting listener when activity is presented.

Comment: Thanks to reply, but what to do if I call getMessageTypes in loop or if getMessageTypes is called in onBindViewHolder of RecyclerView Adapter ?

Comment: @GiruBhai no extra work is needed for calling `getMessageTypes` in loop or in `onBindViewHolder ` because when activity is destroyed all refs from LISTENERS TO ACTIVITY are weak and activity will be collected by GC.

Comment: In onBindViewHolder how can I set instance variable ?

Comment: @GiruBhai save its ref in Activity class (as i said in `onCreate` of `Activity` create it) and send it to `recyclerView Adapter` and the adapter sends it to `ViewHolder`

Comment: But in onBindViewHolder I have to track for position, which I think will be more complex.